# monero regtest generateblocks returns status "BUSY"

Tags: monerod, regtest

I am running a Monero node in --regtest mode. generateblocks always returns status "BUSY". gen_info() does not say it is busy though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `--no-sync` option is preventing generating blocks, filed an issue with Monero developers: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/9124

`v0.18.3.1`